# Solve the inequality $|x-3a|>|x-a|$, $a$ is a positive constant.

Tags: inequality

first I am sorry because I don't speak English well.

I am reading (Pure Mathematics 2 and 3 - Endorsed by CAMBRIDGE) to review what I studied :)

And I try to solve this exercise

> Given that $a$ is a positive constant, Solve the inequality $|x-3a|>|x-a|$.

I don't know what the way should I to use to solve this problem.

- $-\vert x-3a|<x-a<|x-3a\vert $

( because If $|x|<a$ then $-a<x<a$ )

---

Or this way

- $x-3a>|x-a|$,  or  $x-3a<-|x-a|$

(Because if $|x|>a$, then $x<-a$ or $x>a$)

Thanks, And please if you can, use (simple) English language to understand.

Comment: I always find drawing graph for this sort of question easiest method to understand/solve. The graphs of $|x-3a|$ and $|x-a|$ are farily easy to visualize. It has a V-shape where the graphs touch $x$-axis at $3a$ and $a$, and as $a>0$, $3a>a>0$ are on the right side of origin. They obviously meet at one point, and via visualizing you can easily spot where the solution region lies. Only thing to do is to find this intersection point of the graphs

Comment: Intuition here: $x$ is closer to $a$ than to $3a$.

Comment: @user160738 Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphical method. Look at the graphs of the left and right hand side functions $y_1=|x-3a|,y_2=|x-a|$:

[image]

We want to find the interval of $x$ for which $y_1>y_2$, that is, the graph of $y_1$ is higher than the graph of $y_2$. It is:
$$(-\infty,2a)$$

Note: To find the intersection point $(2a,a)$:
$$y_1=y_2 \Rightarrow |x-3a|=|x-a| \Rightarrow -(x-3a)=x-a \Rightarrow x=2a.$$

Comment: Wow, this is the easier solution, Thank you so much.

Comment: You are welcome. But the algebraic method of @DeepSea is quite easy too. Good luck.

Comment: Yeah sure, also his solution so easy and interesting, Thanks all.

Answer (score 3):

hint: square both sides ! $(x-3a)^2 > (x-a)^2$. Can you continue ?

Comment: Indeed this is a good starting hint! Do note that this is only possible since both sides of the inequality are positive. Care if one or both sides are negative (although I suppose with absolute values this isn't an issue)!

Comment: Thanks, but I have another question here:) , if $|a|>|b|$ is that given $a^2>b^2$ ? I know if $a<b$ then that not given $a^2>b^2$. For example $-2>-3$ but $4$ not greater than $9$, but what about modulus?

Comment: @Dima  (If we have $|a|\gt |b|$ we can multiply by $|a|$ getting $|a|^2|\gt |a||b|$, and multiplying the original by $|b|$ gives $|a||b|\gt |b|^2$). Going forward this requires a little care - squaring is fine because both sides of the inequality are positive. But $a$ is not guaranteed to be positive, and if you divide through by a negative number you reverse the inequality, so you will need to consider cases.

Comment: @Dima $|a|>|b|\implies |a|^2>|b|^2\implies a^2>b^2$, since squares are *always non-negative*.

Comment: Thanks all, I got this:

${(x-3a)}^2>{(x-a)}^2$ ,

$x^2-6ax+9a^2 > x^2-2ax+a^2$ ,

$8a^2 > 4ax$

So $x<2a$

Comment: @MarkBennet Thank you so much, I understand that.

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder Thank you :)

Comment: @JihoonKang Thank you :)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do like this:

We see that $x=3a$ is not solution. Say $x\ne 3a$. Then we can write:

$$ \Big|{x-a\over x-3a}\Big| < 1$$

So we are interested when is $f(x) = {x-a\over x-3a}$ between $-1$ and $1$.

Draw a graph and see when $f(x) =-1$ ($f(x)$ can't be $1$). You get $x\in (-\infty , 2a)$.